# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity

Tags: java, android

I've published an app http://goo.gl/1cs2NO  it's works fine the majority of devices, but i'm getting this error,and i don't know how to solve it :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{aladin888.dessin/aladin888.dessin.Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4512)
at aladin888.dessin.Splash.<init>(Splash.java:49)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
```

My manifest is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="aladin888.dessin"
    android:versionCode="11"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>    


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EasyPaint"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Any helpwould be very appreciated!

---

UPDATE

---

Here's the code at splash.java

```
public void run() {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(3000);

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName("aladin888.dessin",
            Line 49---------------->            "aladin888.dessin.EasyPaint");
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

Should it be simply EasyPaint ?

Comment: Can you post the code of your Splash activity? Error seems to be there

Comment: To be particular, post a chunk of code around line 49 which i suppose is the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. vivek, can you check the code please?

Comment: It should be just EasyPaint. Try and tell

Comment: i tried,it's should be with package name.. I guess the problem is because i inserted an interestitial banner in splash activity, and it's switchs to another activity while a banner is loading.. do you have an S5? because i'm getting a lot of errors with this device, but it's works fine on others.